# Ruby Iteration - Trying to match two numbers in a single pass

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

Say I have a an array like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and I have two variables like this:

```
 b = 3
 c = 4
```

I want to do something like this:

```
  a.each do |i| 
    if(b = = i) and (c == i.next(I don't think I can do this))
    return true
    end
    end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Steve G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use

```
a.each_slice
```

To get a series of paired objects.

Use each_cons as suggested by steenslag or glenn mcdonald.

Comment: No, `a.each_slice(2)` will give you [1,2] [3,4] and [5,6], which wouldn't work if you were looking for b=2 c-3.

Answer (score 3):

each_cons does what you want:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b=3
c=4
a.each_cons(2){|v1, v2| puts(b == v1 && c == v2)}
# output:
# false
# false
# true
# false
# false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.each_cons(2).include?([b,c])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to do it in a loop, or could you simply track if each variable is a `member?` of the array in question? Or put them into a hash/set and make sure each key is contained? Or keep the loop, and just keep logical-ORing whether or each var is a `member?` Or add a `members?` method to Array, and pass in an array to check against, or...

That should be enough ideas to get you started.